# ReferenceTable overflow though not using JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

After adding some XML-files(and images) to my android App, the app crashes on Android 2.2. This is the commit where I added the files: https://github.com/chaosbastler/opentraining/commit/03e90e3d6c083f5622e4ba36190a0358d5d40894

On Android 2.3.3 everything works properly. This is the error log:

```
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   502: 0x43ee3340 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   503: 0x43ee33a0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   504: 0x43ee33f8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   505: 0x43ee3458 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   506: 0x43ee34a8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   507: 0x43ee3500 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   508: 0x43ee3558 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   509: 0x43ee35b8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   510: 0x43ee3618 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308):   511: 0x43ee3678 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-14 08:34:45.796: W/dalvikvm(308): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
10-14 08:34:45.806: W/dalvikvm(308):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 164B
10-14 08:34:45.806: W/dalvikvm(308):   510 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (510 unique)
10-14 08:34:45.806: W/dalvikvm(308):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 2108B
10-14 08:34:45.806: W/dalvikvm(308): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 16552 bytes
10-14 08:34:45.806: E/dalvikvm(308): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
```

I do not use any JNI and this seems to by a bug of the Android OS itself. Any suggestions except dropping support for Android 2.2?

Comment: How many strings does your xml contain?

Comment: There are 99 XML files processed when the app starts,each one should have < 50 Strings. Average per file may be 20.

Comment: Too bad… Have you tried 2.2 on a device, or on emulator?

Comment: Tried both, same error. And changing the emulator to 2.3.3 solved the problem(did not change RAM, VM Heap, ...).